# My pointers and struct code is displaying garbage values

Tags: c

Currently, I am trying to create a program that takes inventory of a stores products. I have been able to create a function that allows the user to input new items in a struct array but when I attempt to print the values I get garbage values. (Please ignore the switch statements as the code is work in progress).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    char item_Number[3];
    char item_Name[20];
    float item_Profit;
    float latest_Price;
    unsigned int stock;
    unsigned int total_Sold;
    struct InventoryItemType *next;
}InventoryItemType;
void MainMenu();
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *(*));
void addItem(InventoryItemType, int i);

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    char selection;
    int count=1;
    InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE] ;

    inventoryItems[0]=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        MainMenu();
        scanf(" %c", &selection);
        switch(selection) 
        {
        case 'A' :
            displayInventory(inventoryItems);
            break;
        case 'B' :
        case 'C' :
            inventoryItems[count]= (InventoryItemType*)malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
            addItem(*inventoryItems[count], count);
            continue;
        case 'D' :
        case 'E' :
        case 'F' :
        case 'G' :
        case 'H' :
        default :
            printf("Invalid\n" );
        }
        printf("Bottom of code\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}
void MainMenu()
{
    printf("A. Display Inventory\n");
    printf("B. Display Sales\n");
    printf("C. Add Item\n");
    printf("D. Remove Item\n");
    printf("E. Enter Shipment\n");
    printf("F. Update Sales\n");
    printf("G. Sort\n");
    printf("H. Exit\n");
    printf("Make a selection\n");
}
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *display)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Name:%s\n", display[i].item_Name);
        printf("Stock:%d\n", display[i].stock);
        printf("Price:%.2f\n", display[i].latest_Price);
        printf("Total Value:%.2f\n", (display[i].stock)*(display[i].latest_Price));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void addItem(InventoryItemType display)
{

    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");
    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", display.item_Name);
    printf("\nEnter Item no: \n");
    scanf("%s", display.item_Number);

    printf("\nEnter Stock: \n");
    scanf("%d", &display.stock);

    printf("\nPurchase Price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &display.latest_Price);
}
```

### Update

I attempted to apply all answers (with a series of trial and error) and came up with this code. I currently have the code properly taking in a new item and displaying that item, but it breaks down after adding more items(if I continue through the errors I get garbage display values). I am pretty certain it has to do with the way in which I am allocating memory via malloc. My goal is to use malloc to create the space for the item before initializing values.

Edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    char item_Number[4];
    char item_Name[20];
    float item_Profit;
    float latest_Price;
    float selling_Price;
    unsigned int stock;
    unsigned int total_Sold;
}InventoryItemType;
void MainMenu();
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *, int);
void displaySales(InventoryItemType *, int);
InventoryItemType *addItem(InventoryItemType *, int);

int main()
{
    int i=0, item_count=0;
    char selection;
    InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE];
    while(1)
    {
        MainMenu();
        scanf(" %c", &selection);
        switch(selection) 
        {
        case 'A' :
            displayInventory(*inventoryItems, item_count);
            break;
        case 'B' :
            displaySales(*inventoryItems, item_count);
            break;
        case 'C' :
            inventoryItems[item_count]=(InventoryItemType*)malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
            inventoryItems[item_count]=addItem(inventoryItems[item_count],item_count);
            item_count++;
            continue;
        case 'D' :
        case 'E' :
        case 'F' :
        case 'G' :
        case 'H' :
        default :
            printf("Invalid Entry\n" );
            system("pause");
        }
        system("cls");
    }
}
void MainMenu()
{
    printf("A. Display Inventory\n");
    printf("B. Display Sales\n");
    printf("C. Add Item\n");
    printf("D. Remove Item\n");
    printf("E. Enter Shipment\n");
    printf("F. Update Sales\n");
    printf("G. Sort\n");
    printf("H. Exit\n");
    printf("Make a selection\n");
}
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *display, int key)
{
    if(display[0].item_Name == NULL)
    {
        printf("No stock");
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<key; i++)
        {
            printf("Item No.:%s\n", display[i].item_Number);
            printf("Item Name:%s\n", display[i].item_Name);
            printf("Item Stock:%d\n", display[i].stock);
            printf("Item Purchased Price:%.2f\n", display[i].latest_Price);
            printf("Total Value of Items:%.2f\n", (display[i].stock)*(display[i].latest_Price));
            printf("\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
void displaySales(InventoryItemType *display, int key)
{
    int i;
    float total_profit=0;
    for(i=0; i<key; i++)
    {
        printf("Item No.:%s\n", display[i].item_Number);
        printf("Item Name:%s\n", display[i].item_Name);
        printf("Number of Item Sold:%d\n", display[i].total_Sold);
        printf("Item Selling Price:%.2f\n", display[i].selling_Price);
        printf("Total Profit from Item:%.2f\n", (display[i].selling_Price-display[i].latest_Price)*display[i].total_Sold);
        total_profit=total_profit+((display[i].selling_Price-display[i].latest_Price)*display[i].selling_Price);
        if(i==key)
        printf("Total Over-all Profit:%.2f", total_profit);
        system("pause");
    }
}
InventoryItemType *addItem(InventoryItemType *change, int key)
{
    InventoryItemType *current= (InventoryItemType*)malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");
    printf("Enter Item no: \n");
    scanf("%s", current[key].item_Number);
    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", current[key].item_Name);
    printf("Enter Stock: \n");
    scanf("%d", &current[key].stock);
    printf("Enter Purchase Price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &current[key].latest_Price);
    current[key].selling_Price=(current[key].latest_Price)*1.5;
    current[key].total_Sold=0;
    change=current;
    system("cls");
    return change;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE] ;` you have an array of pointers, but call `displayInventory(inventoryItems);` when `displayInventory` takes a `InventoryItemType *`.

Comment: you have an array of `InventoryItemType` pointers.. I suspect you want an array of `InventoryItemType` objects.

Comment: @yano Looks like OP is `malloc`ing the elements of `inventoryItems`, so I don't think that is the case.  I'm more curious about what's happening in `addItem`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Oh you're right... Still with a (relatively small) array I'd prefer to use objects in automatic storage here rather than `malloc`ing each one.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons addItem is supposed to add a new inventory item which should include the name of the item, item number(arbitrary but not repeatable), quantity (stock), and purchase price. Please have mercy I am very new to struct, arrays, and pointers.

Comment: `addItem` takes only 1 argument, you are passing 2.

Comment: What's the point of the `count` variable?

Comment: @Pablo Yikes, that mistake came from trying to mess around with the code.. Please ignore the second variable. The Function call should be 
     addItem(*inventoryItems[count]);

Comment: @Trial'n'Error Name checks out. Anyways, you are passing a copy of an `InventoryItemType` to `addItem`.  Any changes you make to `display` are done only to the local copy.  Also you use the address-of operator for half of the time and not the other half.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, The local variable is not carried through to main function and therefore I get garbage values... got it. By that logic my function should be returning something then no?

Comment: @Trial'n'Error You could return an InventoryItemType in that function.  There is no need to pass in any arguments to that function as you can just create an `InventoryItemType` in the function and return it.  Otherwise, if you wish to pass it in as an argument, you should be passing in a pointer to it, that way you'll be able to make changes to the original.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of bugs/conflicts. Too many to comment on individually. I've annotated and corrected the code, showing bugs and before/after. There is still more work to do, but this should get you closer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    char item_Number[3];
    char item_Name[20];
    float item_Profit;
    float latest_Price;
    unsigned int stock;
    unsigned int total_Sold;
    struct InventoryItemType *next;
} InventoryItemType;

void MainMenu();

#if 0
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *(*));
#else
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *,int);
#endif

#if 0
void addItem(InventoryItemType, int i);
#else
void addItem(InventoryItemType *);
#endif

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    char selection;

    // NOTE/BUG: starting at 1 will leave item 0 undefined
#if 0
    int count=1;
#else
    int count=0;
#endif

    // better to do this with a stack array than pointers to malloc'ed items
#if 0
    InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE] ;
#else
    InventoryItemType inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE] ;
#endif

#if 0
    // NOTE/BUG: this will segfault because inventoryItems is undefined here
    inventoryItems[0]=NULL;
#endif

    while (1) {
        MainMenu();
        scanf(" %c", &selection);
        switch(selection) {
        case 'A' :
#if 0
            displayInventory(inventoryItems);
#else
            displayInventory(inventoryItems,count);
#endif
            break;
        case 'B' :
        case 'C' :
#if 0
            inventoryItems[count]= (InventoryItemType*)malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
            addItem(*inventoryItems[count], count);
#else
            addItem(&inventoryItems[count]);
            count += 1;
#endif
            continue;
        case 'D' :
        case 'E' :
        case 'F' :
        case 'G' :
        case 'H' :
        default :
            printf("Invalid\n" );
        }
        printf("Bottom of code\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}

void MainMenu()
{
    printf("A. Display Inventory\n");
    printf("B. Display Sales\n");
    printf("C. Add Item\n");
    printf("D. Remove Item\n");
    printf("E. Enter Shipment\n");
    printf("F. Update Sales\n");
    printf("G. Sort\n");
    printf("H. Exit\n");
    printf("Make a selection\n");
}

#if 0
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType display)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Name:%s\n", display[i].item_Name);
        printf("Stock:%d\n", display[i].stock);
        printf("Price:%.2f\n", display[i].latest_Price);
        printf("Total Value:%.2f\n", (display[i].stock)*(display[i].latest_Price));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void addItem(InventoryItemType display)
{

    // NOTE/BUG: because this is passed by _value_ nothing will be retained
    // after function return

    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");
    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", display.item_Name);
    printf("\nEnter Item no: \n");
    scanf("%s", display.item_Number);

    printf("\nEnter Stock: \n");
    scanf("%d", &display.stock);

    printf("\nPurchase Price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &display.latest_Price);
}
#else
void displayInventory(InventoryItemType *item,int count)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++, item++) {
        printf("Name:%s\n", item->item_Name);
        printf("Stock:%d\n", item->stock);
        printf("Price:%.2f\n", item->latest_Price);
        printf("Total Value:%.2f\n", (item->stock)*(item->latest_Price));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void addItem(InventoryItemType *item)
{

    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");

    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", item->item_Name);

    printf("\nEnter Item no: \n");
    scanf("%s", item->item_Number);

    printf("\nEnter Stock: \n");
    scanf("%d", &item->stock);

    printf("\nPurchase Price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &item->latest_Price);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your code.

```
InventoryItemType *inventoryItems[MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE] ;
```

This declares an array of dimension `MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE` of `InventoryItemType`
pointers. These pointers are uninitialized, so you need to allocate memory for
it. You do it here:

```
inventoryItems[count]= (InventoryItemType*)malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
```

1. [Don't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
2. The `count` variable is initialized to 1 and it is never changed. So every
   time you are allocating new memory for `inventoryItems[1]` and you are losing
   the pointer of the previous `malloc` call, thus it's leaking.

When you print your data structure, you do:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Name:%s\n", display[i].item_Name);
        ...
```

but `inventoryItems[i]` is for all `i != 1` uninitialized, this yield undefined
behaviour.

What's the point of having an array of `InventoryItemType` pointers when the
structure itself has a pointer `next` pointer for the next item in the inventory. It seems you
are mixing concepts here, linked lists vs arrays. I'd suggest you pick one and
stick to it.

Why did you

```
void addItem(InventoryItemType display);
```

declare `addItem` like this? `display` is only a copy of the orginal, so any
change of the values of `display` will only affect `display`, not the original.
So when you do

```
addItem(*inventoryItems[count], count);
```

you are passing a copy to `addItem` and you only change the copy,
`inventoryItems[count]` remains unchanged. Also your function takes only one
parameter, you are passing it two.

`addItem` should take a pointer, so that the changes are done through the
pointer into the original. The function should look like this:

```
int addItem(InventoryItemType *display);
{

    if(display == NULL)
        return 0;

    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");
    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    if(scanf("%19s", display->item_Name) != 1)
        return 0;

    clear_stdin();

    printf("\nEnter Item no: \n");
    if(scanf("%2s", display->item_Number) != 1)
        return 0;

    clear_stdin();

    printf("\nEnter Stock: \n");
    if(scanf("%d", &display->stock) != 1)
        return 0;

    printf("\nPurchase Price: \n");
    if(scanf("%f", &display->latest_Price) != 1)
        return 0;


    return 1;
}
```

The function should return 1 on success, 0 otherwise. The caller of `addItem`
will know whether `addItem` failed or not. If you declare the function as
`void`, then you will never know if the function failes or not.

And `clear_stdin` could look like this:

```
 void clear_stdin(void)
 {
     int c;
     while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
 }
```

---

**edit**

As you've made an update and you've decided to use the array, then I can give
you a few more pointers.

You are declaring to much memory. Either you allocate memory before `addItem`
and pass the newly allocated memory to `addItem`, or you allocate the memory in
`addItem` itself and return it. Your `addItem` already does that, so the first
line

```
inventoryItems[item_count]=(InventoryItemType*)malloc(sizeof(InventoryItemType));
```

is not necessary, because `addItem` does that for you.

I'd change `addItem` to look like this:

```
InventoryItemType *addItem(void)
{
    InventoryItemType *current = calloc(1, sizeof *current);
    if(current == NULL)
        return NULL;

    printf("\nEnter details of item \n\n");
    printf("Enter Item no: \n");
    scanf("%2s", current->item_Number);

    clear_stdin();

    printf("Enter Item Name: \n");
    scanf("%20s", current->item_Name);

    clear_stdin();

    printf("Enter Stock: \n");
    scanf("%d", &current->stock);
    printf("Enter Purchase Price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &current->latest_Price);
    current->selling_Price=(current->latest_Price)*1.5;
    current->total_Sold=0;
    system("cls");

    return current;
}
```

Because `addItem` allocates the memory for the new object, you don't need to
pass the array nor the index (or key) where you want to store it. Then in the
`main` you can do this:

```
case 'C':
    // checking that you don't step outside of bounds
    if(item_count == MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE - 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Array is full\n");
        break;
    }

    inventoryItems[item_count] = addItem();
    if(inventoryItems[item_count] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        break;
    }

    item_count++;
    continue;

case 'D':
    ...
```

Comment: How would I work around not casting Malloc? My goal is to create the memory required for a new item before initializing its values.

Comment: @Trial'n'Error *How would I work around not casting Malloc?* by not casting it. *My goal is to create the memory required for a new item before initializing its values* I know that, but like I said in the answer, you are mixing concepts here. Do you want a linked list or an array. The correct way depends on what approach you want to take.

Comment: Array, i have taken out the linked list.

Comment: I currently get this error for calloc (and malloc) when attempting to create the memory for the item. "                                                    
                                                                                                           
 14 IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "InventoryItemType *"
"

Comment: @Trial'n'Error are you compiling you C code with a C++ compiler? This might explain the error?

Comment: you pointed me to the right direction. In Visual studio apparently this syntax must be used: **"InventoryItemType *current = (InventoryItemType*) calloc(1, sizeof *current);"**. I no longer get errors, however I do have garbage values still for any other print out other than the first one...Here is an image of out with two items:[image](https://ibb.co/kwWKAS)

Comment: @Trial'n'Error as far as I know, VS C compiler is a C++ compiler in disguise and that's why you need the cast in VS. The error you see is because you are passing to `displayInventory` the incorrect type, it should be: `displayInventory(inventoryItems, item_count);` and `if(display[0].item_Name == NULL)` will never be true because `item_Name` is not a pointer, is a `char` array. You have to get the types right, read the warnings of the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. Everything works great and I learned a lot from your explanations.